# How to calculate $\min \|J\Delta\tau + D\|_*$?

Tags: matrices, optimization, convex-optimization, closed-form, nuclear-norm

I would like to calculate

$$\min_{\tau} ||J_1 \tau_1 + \cdots + J_p \tau_p + D ||_*$$

where $\tau_1, \dots, \tau_p \in \mathbb{R}$, $J_1, \dots, J_p, D \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and $\|\cdot\|_*$ is sum of its singular values. Since $m$ and $n$ can be up to some hundred, the $O(n^6)$ interior-point method is definitely too slow for me.

Comment: There is no closed-form solution in general; your tag suggests that's what you want. Right? Otherwise, this is a problem that can be solved by a semidefinite programming solver, though it takes a bit of transformation.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a perfect reference (PDF): ["Interior-point method for nuclear norm approximation with
application to system identification"](http://www.seas.ucla.edu/~vandenbe/publications/nucnrm.pdf). One approach would be to convert the problem to a semidefinite program
$$\begin{array}{ll}
\text{minimize} & 
\frac{1}{2}\left(\mathop{\textrm{Tr}}(W_1)+\mathop{\textrm{Tr}}(W_2)\right) \\
\text{subject to} & \begin{bmatrix} W_1 & J_1 \tau_1 + \cdots + J_p \tau_p + D \\ \left( J_1 \tau_1 + \cdots + J_p \tau_p + D \right)^T & W_2 \end{bmatrix} \succeq 0
\end{array}$$
and solve this using one of the many semidefinite programming solvers available. But as this paper shows, a custom solver will often be more efficient, particularly if $m\ll n$ or $m\gg n$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the interior-point method seems too slow for me.

Comment: Have you already tried it? It would have been helpful for you to have said so in the original question so I wouldn't waste my time. But read the paper anyway. It has references to other methods, including first-order methods.

Comment: I am sorry that I did not put it so clear. I am currently using [Inexact Augmented Lagrange Multiplier Method]( http://yima.csl.illinois.edu/psfile/Lin09-MP.pdf), and on the paper, the author stated that it is much faster than the interior-point method. However, my problem is much simplier, so I believe there should be some faster algorithm. I did not say these in my problem statement because I did not want to mislead others.